# Is there a use case when traffic needs to be secured between 2 AWS instances?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

According to Amazon's security white paper, it is not possible sniff traffic by other tenants 
http://awsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf

Question:  Is there a use case when traffic needs to be secured between 2 AWS instances (or resources) belonging to the **same AWS account?** For instance, traffic between

1) an instance in EC2 classic and other instance in a VPC?
2) an instance in EC2 classic and an RDS instance a) in the same region b) in an other region (assuming yes for b) )
3) an instance in a VPC and instance in an other VPC?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 3):

I would never trust that it is secure to transfer information in the clear when a third party controls the medium of communication. Treat communication between your two instances as if it was going over the plain old internet. I don't know much about AWS, but it seems likely that communication between your AWS instances *would* go across the plain old internet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely that traffic within your VPC can easily be seen by the world.

Having said that, the perfect use case would be when handling sensitive data, e.g credit card information. It makes sense to encrypt the traffic to safeguard against possible bugs in AWS, or even vulnerabilities in how you architect your VPC.